# Would a “black hole bomb” using dyson sphere and superradiant scattering destroy the blackhole?

Tags: black-holes, supernova

I watched part of this Kurzgesagt video (link sends you to the video part)
https://youtu.be/ulCdoCfw-bY?t=323

and part of this pbs spacetime video (link sends you to the video part)
https://youtu.be/UjgGdGzDFiM?t=633

Which depict putting mirrors around a black hole in a dyson sphere type of configuration and shining light into it to harness its energy through superradiant scattering. However, if this energy isn't released, it grows exponentially as the light bounces off the mirrors taking energy from the balck hole, and what was once a black hole engine turns into a black hole bomb, going supernova as a result. I was curious as to if the black hole itself would be destroyed in the process or if it just goes supernova and then like absorbs the supernova? What is the effect of this "black hole bomb" thing?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have had the exact same question closed before. Instead of writing a new one, you could edit the first one and wait to see if there are votes to open it, or if the moderators open it.   The explanation of the videos informs us that it is a science fiction scenario, not possible to be implemented within our world which is described with mainstream physics. One cannot put mirrors around a black hole of mainstream physics is the most glaring sciiece fiction assumption. They will inevitably be absorbed, together with the spaceships  and all the rest needed for the scenario

Comment: The closure of this question as "non-mainstream" is ridiculous. It has been the subject of multiple PRL and Nature papers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107921/discussion-on-question-by-ashy-would-a-black-hole-bomb-using-dyson-sphere-and).

Comment: @mmeent Some links to those papers might help towards getting this question reopened.

Comment: @DavidZ Here is the link to the original highly cited original 1972 Press&Teukolsky Nature paper that coined the term: https://www.nature.com/articles/238211a0 (unfortunately is behind a paywall, but that should not be an issue for those of us with institutional access)

Comment: Here is a highly cited PRD paper by Cardoso et al. available of the arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0404096

Comment: Here is a relatively recent PRL (available of the arxiv): https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0465

Comment: Each of these has over a 100 citations, and has "black hole bomb" in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A black hole bomb draws its power from the rotation of the black hole (through a process known as superradiance). The effect of the "bomb"* on the black hole would therefore be to spin it down, converting part of its rotational energy (and therefore mass) to energy in the "bomb". The end result is a black hole with a lower spin than the one you began with, but otherwise it will come out unscathed. In fact, it will be bigger than the one you started with, despite losing mass. (This is the [second law of black hole mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics) at play.)

Whether the same can be said of the Dyson sphere is another matter, as it is likely to melt under the enormous energy involved.

In the comments it was argued that

> Physics means it should be experimentally possible to construct such a sphere, ant it is absolutely not, by the behavior of space time around a black hole. The people moving the material to construct it would end in the black hole before starting.

This depends on where you would build de mirror. From an engineering perspective it shouldn't be much harder (or easier) than building a Dyson sphere around an active star of the same mass, if you build it at the same radius. The physical principle behind the bomb does not depend on where you place the mirror, as long as the light is directed back towards the black hole.

In fact, it does not have to be a physical mirror at all. The same effect can be obtained by considering a light (but not massless) bosonic field (such as an axion) around a rotating black hole. The mass of the bosonic field will act in its equations of motion as a natural mirror scattering the field back to the black hole, where it will be amplified again and again. Such a superradiant instability would spin down the black hole and create a boson cloud around the black hole. Overtime, such clouds would decay under emission of gravitational waves, appearing as a monochromatic source.

Search for such sources has been proposed as a way of searching for light boson fields (which could be a dark matter candidate). The non-detection of such sources already puts bounds on the existence of such fields.

*The term "bomb" may not be the best way of describing what happens. As depending on the setup the energy build-up could be quite gradual.

Comment: it cannot be light, as light has zero mass photons.  see my quote from wiki above. The way they are putting limits on candidates for dark matter shows this, A perfectly reasonable hypothesis from the physics point of view , is misused ( photons instead of Xbosons) for science fiction purposes.

Comment: @annav "light" as in "not heavy". This should have been obvious from the mention of an axion as a possible candidate.

Comment: Only electromagnetic light can be reflected by mirrors (the question talks of mirrors)

Comment: @annav Yes, and EM radiation reflected off a mirror satisfies all the conditions needed for the instability to occur. With massive bosons, you don't need  a mirror at all.

Comment: according to what I found , there has to be a mass, otherwise there is no "bomb". The mirror is a random science fiction confusion between Dyson's sphere and the instability . see the phys rev let paper quoted.

Comment: @annav You might actually want to read that paper, rather than just cherry-picking from the press release.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is not closed, I will state here why the proposal  is science fiction.

> [A black hole bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_bomb) is the name given to a physical effect utilizing how a bosonic field impinging on a rotating black hole can be amplified through superradiant scattering. An additional condition which must be met is that **the field must have a rest mass different from zero.**

Bold mine.

As all of main stream physics is based on the zero mass of the photon, a mirror for photons cannot work for this predicted from general relativity mathematics phenomenon.

> [New calculations reported](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v5/s147) in Physical Review Letters show that photons, or photonlike particles, could be considered bomb-making material **if they have a mass.** A massive photon is not theoretically ruled out, but it would have implications for the dispersion of light and the existence of magnetic monopoles. However, the mere existence of spinning (unbombed) black holes constrains this possibility, thus allowing the authors to put the most stringent limit yet on the mass of the photon.
>
> Falling into a black hole means curtains for most things. But physicists have shown that a hypothetical spin-zero particle—called a **scalar boson**—could quantum-mechanically bind to a rotating black hole if the particle’s Compton wavelength (which is inversely proportional to its mass) is roughly equal to the radius of the black hole. The resulting gravitational “atom” would lead to a runaway effect, or bomb, that zaps the hole’s rotational energy in a relatively short time.

Even in an extension of the theoretical model to spin one bosons, the mass constraint remains:

> Paolo Pani, at the Technical University of Lisbon in Portugal, and his colleagues [extended these investigations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0465) to massive spin-one particles, such as massive photons. The calculations in this case are extremely difficult, so the researchers studied slowly rotating black holes and then extrapolated their results to fast rotation. They found that massive spin-one particles trigger more powerful “bombs” than scalar (spin-zero) particles. The observed rotation of supermassive black holes rules out photons ful “bombs” than scalar (spin-zero) particles. The observed rotation of supermassive black holes rules out photons (as well as photonlike particles, that some theories suggest could contribute to dark matter) of mass above $4×10^{−20}$eV.

This is how a theoretical prediction ties up with mainstream physics,  looking for particles  not experimentally observed up to now and setting limits, in this case, since they are so stringent, for the photon itself.

This is a research subject within mainstream physics.

It becomes science fiction  when the vocabulary is used to propose a construction (experimentally impossible in its difficulties) around a black hole that cannot work because photons have zero mass.

Comment: The quote from Wikipedia is wrong (I will amend that shortly), and the paper is misquoted. If you have a massive boson (e.g. a photon), the radiant instability ("bomb") can work without a mirror. It is not saying that you need the boson to be massive in the construction with mirror.

Comment: @mmeent  You cannot have construction with physical mirror for the boson effect. You could have it for the original suggestion by Dyson, who was considering of harnessing the heat/electromagnetic waves from the sun/stars. It is a different experiment/story. Zero mass photons cannot be candidates fro the black hole bomb effect.

Comment: Of course they can. Anybody with even a remote understanding of the underlying physics can see this. Read the original Teukolsky and Press paper if you want.

Comment: for spin one there has to be a mass, in the phys.rev.paper linked

Comment: That is not what that paper says it all. It says that for it to work *without* a mirror the field needs to have mass.

Comment: That is your interpretation, the word "mirror" cannot be found in the paper. They are interested in testing effects beyond the standard model.

Comment: "Massive fields around rotating black holes (BHs) can
trigger a superradiant instability, the so-called “black
hole bomb" is in the introduction to the paper, it is a given. They study the spin one case ( i.e. photons)

Comment: I'll quote from the original Press and Teukolsky (1972) paper: "To illustrate, in a  rather speculative vein, we propose the "black-hole bomb" (closely related to a recent suggestion of Zel'dovich): locate a rotating black hole and construct a  spherical mirror around it. The mirror must reflect low-frequency radio waves (equation (4); and we now make the transition from scalar to electromagnetic fields) with reflectivity $\gtrsim ~99.8%$, so that in one reflexion and subsequent superradiant scattering there is a net amplification. ..."

Comment: "... The system is then unstable against a  number of exponentially growing electro-magnetic modes which will be initiated by random "seed fields" (thermal noise). Because a  typical amplification in one reflexion is $\sim 10^{-3}$ the e-folding time is roughly $\tau\sim 10^3 L/c$ where L is the radius of the mirror. For ease of construction, the mirror should not be too close to the hole; for a  hole of $M_\odot$ an appropriate choice might be $L\sim 10^3$ km, so that$\tau\sim 3  s$.  ..."

Comment: " ... As the mode grows, electromagnetic pressure on the mirror increases until the mirror explodes, releasing the trapped electromagnetic energy in a  time $\sim L/c$. This is  the black-hole bomb." Enough said.